# Installing perl module

Tags: installation, perl

How to install perl module Util.pm .I am missing this module .What is the procedure to install a perl module

Comment: Any particular platform?

Comment: Linux,Cent Os....

Comment: You can usually just do "yum provides */<name of file/module>" to find out what package, if any, provides the module. 
But in this specific case "Util.pm" is a very common name and tens of packages provide it.
You need to identify  which module requires its "Util.pm" by looking at the source or at the path in the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of which platform you may be on, you may be able to install the module using the CPAN shell. You can drop down to the CPAN shell by running the command:

```
perl -MCPAN -e shell
```

and from there use the `install` command to fetch and install the module you need installed.

The [perldoc for CPAN](http://perldoc.perl.org/CPAN.html) is helpful in understanding how to use CPAN and what it does and how it works.

You may use the `i /Util/` command to search modules and packages that match the given pattern. Or, you could go to [search.cpan.org](http://search.cpan.org/) and look for the module you are looking for.

Comment: Do u mean to say install util.pm??

Comment: And how to list and remove modules..

Comment: @Rajeev: I have updated my answer with more information. I am afraid you will have to find the exact name of the module you are looking to install.

Answer (score 2):

I really like cpanm, it makes it very easy to install perl mods.  Have never had a problem with it and saves me a lot of time.

```
cd /tmp
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MI/MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.4008.tar.gz
gunzip App* && tar -xvvf App*
cd App*
perl Makefile.PL
make && make install
```

( make sure you have gcc installed)

Now all you have to do if you want a mod just
cpanm <_MOD_NAME_>
( cpanm POSIX::RT::MQ )  POSIX::RT::MQ is the mod you want / etc

Answer (score 2):

Quite a lot of Perl module are available as rpm packages for CentOS, some in the base repos and quite a few more in rpmforge and epel repos. Easier and faster than using cpan and the module will be updated when you update your CentOS install if an update is available.

See [this page](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories) for a list of extra CentOS repos.

Comment: I upvoted this answer, because using precompiled binaries is faster and cleaner than using CPAN. Specially on a production server

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install Utils, not Util.
The easiest way is to use CPAN. Just type:

```
cpan install Utils
```